# Wire multiple UserControls with separate ViewModels in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, datacontext

I’m tyring to create an WPF MVVM application to edit music albums (cue sheets) with a waveform display. The MainWindow should have the follwing design:

- At the top of the MainWindow will be a MenuBar.
- Below a display of the audio waveform
- Below a display of the audio tracks of the album.

To make the MainWindow.xaml not so big and have some kind of functional separation I decided to create separate view models and views for the waveform display and the album/tracks display. The separate views I’ve created as WPF UserControls each.

In app.xaml the views and view models are connected together:

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
      <Views:Main/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CueAlbumViewModel}">
      <Views:CueAlbum/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:WaveFormViewModel}">
      <Views:Waveform/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Application.Resources>
```

The MainWindow has set the MainViewModel as DataContext:

```
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

The bindings of MainWindow <-> MainViewModel are working so far.

But what's not working is the binding of the UserControls to their custom DataSources in MainWindow. E.g. for the view CueAlbum I tried it this way:

```
      <Views:CueAlbum Grid.Row="1"
                      DataContext="{Binding CueAlbumViewModel}"/>
```

But the connection isn't done properly. The constructor of CueAlbumViewModel isn't called at all.

So, can this be achieved properly in WPF / MVVM without code-behind in the view?

Or is using user controls with own DataContexts in MainWindow bad design at all?

(Another question that might arise after this is solved is how to set the Buttons of the MainWindows ToolbarTray to the dedicated UserContols..)

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding CueAlbumViewModel}"` expects that there is a public CueAlbumViewModel property in the *current* DataContext, i.e. the MainViewModel instance.

Comment: UserControls don't have to have their own data context. It definitely makes sense to use data context from view, where they are hosted

Comment: "*using user controls with own DataContexts*" is bad design when the UserControl explicitly sets it own DataContext, i.e. in its own XAML or code behind. Binding its DataContext in the MainWindow is ok. This should however not be necessary when it is instantiated by a DataTemplate.

Comment: How are your `DataTemplates` being applied? Are you exlicilty creating an instance of a `CueAlbumViewModel` somewhere? You need to share more details.

Comment: No this is missing. So this is probably the reason the constructor isn't called.